# How to sync incomplete replication records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6, data-synchronization, disaster-recovery

if replication breaks and you end up with a couple of records not pushed out to the slave, is there a way to update the slave without stopping locks on the master and manually transferring a new master copy to the slave?

I am very familiar with this process  [fix replication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036652/replication-not-updating-all-tables)   but I am writing a script that must include a method of resyncing disk data in the event of replication failure (a self repairing script)
I am trying to avoid implementing database locks and mysqldump via Python, if possible.

What is a more seemless method to syncing incomplete data following replication failure, one that would be script friendly?

Comment: See the Percona tool kit -- there is a checksum script to discover what is out of sync, plus a script to push the updates necessary.

Comment: @RickJames   the more I dig, the uglier of a solution this appears to be. Surely there is a better solution than this?   https://bpaste.net/show/ce35e126b08b